# Changing numbers in a string r

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame. However, I have similar IDs and these were different observations. What I am trying to do is change the last/last two digit(s) in the column ID. So  for ID alnfru_00001 in row 5 should be alnfru_00006 and so on. this sequence is seen right throughout the data frame even with other IDs. Can anyone provide some assistance?

```
                ID          PFT        area
        1    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        2    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        3    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        4    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        5    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        6    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        7    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        8    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        9    alnfru_00005 alnfru Yukon_Delta....................................

        18   alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        19   alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        20   alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        21   alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        22   alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        23   alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        24   alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
        25   alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta

The data frame should look like this 


            ID          PFT        area
    1    alnfru_00001 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    2    alnfru_00002 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    3    alnfru_00003 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    4    alnfru_00004 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    5    alnfru_00005 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    6    alnfru_00006 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    7    alnfru_00007 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    8    alnfru_00008 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    9    alnfru_00009 alnfru Yukon_Delta....................................

    18   alnfru_00010 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    19   alnfru_00011 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    20   alnfru_00012 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    21   alnfru_00013 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    22   alnfru_00014 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    23   alnfru_00015 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    24   alnfru_00016 alnfru Yukon_Delta
    25   alnfru_00017 alnfru Yukon_Delta
```

Comment: You meant `18   alnfru_00018 alnfru Yukon_Delta` instead of `alnfru_00010`, right? It seems you are skipping some rows when showing us data but ID doesn't follow the same pattern. **Moreover,** if you only want to have this pattern  `alnfru_#####` which starts from 1 to n, please cofirm, and we can help you. Otherwise, your question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the trailing number to track the row number (a little unclear from the question) you can do it like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(PFT = rep("alnfru", 10000))
head(dat)
#>      PFT
#> 1 alnfru
#> 2 alnfru
#> 3 alnfru
#> 4 alnfru
#> 5 alnfru
#> 6 alnfru
```

Given a column encoding what the ID leads with a solution is:

```r
dat$ID <- paste(dat$PFT, sprintf("%05d", 1:nrow(dat)), sep = "_")
dat[c(1:3, 9997:10000),]
#>          PFT           ID
#> 1     alnfru alnfru_00001
#> 2     alnfru alnfru_00002
#> 3     alnfru alnfru_00003
#> 9997  alnfru alnfru_09997
#> 9998  alnfru alnfru_09998
#> 9999  alnfru alnfru_09999
#> 10000 alnfru alnfru_10000
```

If in fact all IDs start with the same leading code you can simply do:

```r
dat$ID <- paste("alnfru", sprintf("%05d", 1:nrow(dat)), sep = "_")
```